# How to make this postman call in the asp.net c# code?

Tags: c#, postman

I have this call in postman which is a post call

postcall

URL:"www.test.com/getsomething/something.aspx"
with data in the body in form-data with the parameter param1 = string of bytecode

[image: Postman Call]

I have tried creating like this

```
var bytesContent = new ByteArrayContent(GetBytesFromString(samlResponse.OuterXml));
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"json\"");
content.Add(bytesContent, "param1");
var response1 = HttpClient.PostAsync("https://www.test.com/getsomething/something.aspx", content);
```

How to make this call in C# work?
The above code that I have tried did not work.

The error is "One or more error has occurred". There is not much detail in the error.

This occurs at Postasync line.

Comment: What did not work about it?   Did you get an error?  Edit your question and add the error text.

Comment: I have added the error. Any suggestion. ?

Comment: The exception that occurred will be a child of the "One or more error has occurred". Depending upon how you are getting the exception information, you need to get the additional detail.

Comment: What content you pass on the body for form-data? Am I using the right one to pass the data?